# I have 5 forms and I want to know how to return to the main form after closing 5th form

Tags: c#-4.0

I have two questions: 
1- I have a project that contains 5 forms, So I want to know how to return to the first form when closing the 5th form.
2- I have two buttons, one is visible on the form and the second one is not. What I wanted to do is to display the second button when the first button is clicked.
I added this code on the Form_load event: btn2.Visible= false, and I added this code under btn1_Click: btn2_Visible=true, but it didn't work. Can anyone help me please?

Form4 newform = new Form4(TextBox1.Text,TextBox2.Text);
   newform.Show();   // this code is in form1.

```
this.Hide();
```

Then I created a button in Form4 to create Form 5 using the same code: 
        RForm Form5 = new RForm(Label1.Text, Label2.Text);

```
 this.Hide(); // this is in Form 4
 Form5.Show();
```

To return to Form1, I created a button in form5 :

private void c_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();

Comment: Do you have MDI parent/child set up? How do you open those forms?

Comment: No, I just added new form and created each one using this code:  Form Form5 = new Form5  under a buttons

Comment: this might be a basic method, but I just started learning to code in c#

Comment: Can you update the question with relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Parent` property of your forms. For instance, to open Form4,

```
Form4 form4 = new Form4();
form4.Parent = this; // Reference to current Form1 instance
this.Hide();
form4.Show();
```

In the event handler in `Form4`, check for the parent property and show that.

```
(form4.Parent as Form1).Show();
this.Close();
```

You would also want to handle the `Closing` event if user closes the form any other way than your button.

For the second part, as long as event handlers are wired up properly, this should work. In the event handler, `btn2.Visible = true` would work.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried the code but for some reason it give me an error.